# Angular2 App reloading after emitting event

Tags: angular

I am quiet new to Angular2 and SPA developement, so please excuse, if this is a stupid question.

I am following a tutorial. Several components are used, and when clicking on one element, an event shall be emitted, consumed by other components.

```
  <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix" (click)="onSelect()">
```

In the respective component the following method is called

```
onSelect(event) {
event.stopPropagation();
console.log("Emitting event in recipe-item.component");
//this.recipeSelected.emit(this.recipe);
}
```

I commented the last line out on purpose, because I was trying to debug the thing. Normally the event shoud be emitted and consumed. But instantly after the log entry, the App reloads. In chrome in the console I can see "Navigated to [url]".

Could anyone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: My guess is, that you somehow cause a form submit which causes the reload, but it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: check your console log for errors

Comment: I did - I preserved the console log and there are no errors. 

I did think about that form submit thing. But there is no form defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove href="" and you will make it work. You are redirecting to the page and actually reloading the page. Angular 2 should use only angular 2 router.

So you will have the next html code:

```
<a class="list-group-item clearfix" (click)="onSelect()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `stopPropagation()` you should use `preventDefault()` or return `false`:

```
onSelect(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  console.log("Emitting event in recipe-item.component");
  this.recipeSelected.emit(this.recipe);
}
```

or

```
(click)="onSelect();false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the button type to "button" if using any form. It worked for me

Comment: Hello, to improve your answer you could add an code example.